# UEFI install (14.04) boots to GRUB command prompt, no GUI

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I just installed zorin 9 core (14.04) on my Hard-Disk in UEFI mode. But, when I boot, all that comes up is a GRUB2 command line.  I've searched for solution and came up with this command

`configfile (hd0,2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

and it boots just fine. This command was from [arch-linux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/) and they said to copy the grub.cfg to the efi partition, but I don't know exactly what to copy or if I'm even in the right place. they also mentioned

`"grub-mkimage"`

but I'm not that much of an advanced user to get what all they were saying. could I just create a startup script that has that command in it? Here is the link - [GRUB 2 showing prompt instead of menu.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=124213)

Comment: so, does it boot successfully if you enter `configfile (hd0,2)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` on the prompt? what does `ls` give you? what does `ls (hd0,1)/` or `ls (hd0,2)/` give you?

Comment: Actually just create a grub.cfg file in /efi/ubuntu or whereever grub & shim files are. And add just that one configfile line to tell it to use grub.cfg in your install.

Answer (score 1):

*Try these steps:*

```
Step 1: Boot Ubuntu Live Media in UEFI Mode
Step 2: Mount Zorin OS partition on /mnt
Step 3: Mount EFI partition on /mnt/boot/efi
Step 4: Mount /dev/pts /dev/ /proc /sys /var/run /run on /mnt$i
Step 5: Chroot into /mnt
Step 6: Install grub2-efi, run grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg, run grub-install /dev/sda
Step 6: Done. Reboot.
```

*I have done a dualboot Windows 8 and Zorin system myself.*

*A good video on how is here:* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHt3jij63o4

*Note:*
Make sure UEFI in enabled in the Bios!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I just ran into the same issue installing Ubuntu 14.04 server. The solution in my case was simply to change the filesystem of the /boot from xfs to ext4, which I could do from the installer. After that it works as expected.