# Arch Linux: GRUB boots into command line

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub2

For some reason, after installing GRUB (and running grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/arch/grub.cfg), it boots into the command-line interface, not the normal GUI.

I know [there’s a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163647/arch-linux-boots-into-grub-command-line) on the forum, but my case is different. They had to make a directory and copy the files over. Unlike them, I don’t have to do that, I can boot straight into arch GRUB. But like that case, however, it only boots me into the normal (not rescue mode, the one you usually reach when pressing ‘c’ on the GUI) command line.

Can I configure it to be a GUI, and how? (P.S. my disk’s boot mode is UEFI, not BIOS.)

Comment: Did you install a GUI in the first place?

Comment: Did you remember to "grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg" when installing (I've forgotten to do that before)?

Comment: @DanielMassey Yes, I did.

Comment: @muru How do you do that?

Comment: @utaker - Maybe try `cp /boot/efi/EFI/arch/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg` (create the /boot/grub directory with `mkdir` if not present), then reboot?

Answer (score 1):

> it only boots me into the command line

If this is a normal command line, and not the rescue shell or so, you have reached systemd target "multi-user". You want "graphical".

Muru is right asking about "GUI in the first place?".

The rest is a question of basic systemd configuration.

---

Comment: And no, it wasn’t a “deliberate act of confusion”, I was in a hurry and didn’t think this whole question through. But yes, parts of the question are vague, and I believe I have fixed them now.

Comment: So you are able to start a GUI and then press 'c'? And now boot directly to GUI? This is still a systemd question, not grub, I would say. You know about these target links in systemd? And that arch linux only gives you the pieces, plus the info?