# Different boot partitions for dual boot

Tags: partition, grub2, dual-boot

I finally decided to manage partitions in my hard drive and install different OS's.
I have used Ubuntu for a few years, and I'm fairly familiar with its installation.
Now I want to try OpenSUSE, but I found its installation process a bit more... robust. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to follow all that I did there.

OpenSUSE is running properly, but now I can't go back to Ubuntu.  At startup I get a SUSE grub menu; and it gives me an error when I choose Ubuntu: `you need to load the kernel first`, or something of the like.

The partitions that I made are the following:

```
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1050624   13633535  12582912    6G Linux swap
/dev/sda3  1452863488 1465147391  12283904  5.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda4    13633536   63965183  50331648   24G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5    63965184  441452543 377487360  180G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6   441452544  491784191  50331648   24G Linux filesystem
```

The first `sda1` was setup for Ubuntu, and I initially tried to use it for OpenSUSE as well.  I believe this is where my problem is.  Do I need to create another EFI/boot partition to start OpenSuse, or in this case Ubuntu?

The two 24Gb partitions `sda4` and `sda6` are for the root folders in each OS.  And the 180Gb in `sda5` is the home folder.

Please let me know how can I proceed to fix this?

Comment: 1. You should have only one EFI partition. 2. Also, just one swap would be enough too...but this one is a matter of taste. 3. Check that in the EFI partition you have .efi files for both systems (Ubuntu and openSUSE). If not, then something is probably wrong. 4. Did you try to regenerate the grub config from openSUSE? Usually you do that with `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: 4. I don't recall any grub steps during installation.  I believe I just chose that boot partition, and it may have overriden the EFI for the first system Ubuntu. 
I cannot run the command that you indicate, `command not found`.

Comment: Use EFI boot.  I just commented on a post here <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145503/uefi-install-14-04-boots-to-grub-command-prompt-no-gui/235564#235564> where this sort of thing is accomplished.

Comment: 4. Surprisingly (to me) I do have both systems listed in /boot/efi/EFI.  I could run your command for `grub2` instead of `grub` and got a warning about `lvmetad` being disabled and `No volume groups found`.  The good news is it did find Ubuntu.  I'm rebooting to try it out.

Comment: This edit didn't fix the issue.  The error is the same.

Comment: @Paul, I followed your recommendation... no success.  This time I ran the commands with `grub` instead of `grub2` because I couldn't install `grub2-efi` while in (k)ubuntu Live Media.

Comment: I did notice that I can boot Ubuntu from the boot menu if I start the computer like that.

Comment: Indeed, some systems just call these commands `grub-*`, others call `grub2-*`. Okay, I expected it would find Ubuntu, this is nice. However, now I have no idea why it still doesn't work -- it should.

Comment: I tried running `grub-mkconfig -o ...` from the other installation, and it didn't fix the issue either.  The whole error is `/boot/vmlinz-3.19.0-3.0-generic.efi.signed has invalid signature` `you need to load the kernel first`.  Perhaps this explains more.